# Why do i see - "WhatsApp/2.19.291 A" in my Nginx Access.log

Tags: nginx

I see many entries for - "WhatsApp/2.19.291 A" , in my Nginx access log , these do not occur in the error log . A sample of these is as seen below -

```
- - - [31/Oct/2019:11:43:45 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2410 "-" "WhatsApp/2.19.291 A" "-"
- - - [31/Oct/2019:11:43:48 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "WhatsApp/2.19.291 A" "-"
- - - [31/Oct/2019:11:43:48 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "WhatsApp/2.19.291 A" "-"
- - - [31/Oct/2019:11:43:48 +0530] "GET /pyfintrader/index/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "WhatsApp/2.19.291 A" "-"
- - - [31/Oct/2019:11:49:54 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2402 "-" "HTTP Banner Detection (https://security.ipip.net)" "-"
```

I have googled for this but cant find anything relevant - kindly do let me know if this question belongs on ServerFault or InfoSecurity forums - thanks

EDIT -1 ---

I have further gone through the - `journalctl` and the nginx error log , cant find anything relevant to share .

```
$ journalctl -xn15000 | grep php > php_log_fromJournalLctl.txt
$ sudo nano php_log_fromJournalLctl.txt

$ journalctl -xn15000 | grep What > whatssap_log_fromJournalLctl.txt
$ sudo nano whatssap_log_fromJournalLctl.txt

$ journalctl -xn15000 | grep nginx > nginx_log_fromJournalLctl.txt
$ sudo nano nginx_log_fromJournalLctl.txt 

$ journalctl -xn15000 | grep Failed > failed_log_fromJournalLctl.txt
$ sudo nano failed_log_fromJournalLctl.txt 

$ journalctl -xn15000 | grep sshd > sshd_log_fromJournalLctl.txt
$ sudo nano sshd_log_fromJournalLctl.txt
```

I see one vote to close this question - pls do leave a comment why this question is irrelevant - thanks

Comment: This seems to be a User-Agent string. Whatsapp fetches resource to generate preview when someone shared a link in a chat

Comment: @AlexC - Thanks Alex - yes it seems to be true . I shared a Nginx hosted webserver / website URL link with someone ,  within a Whatsapp chat - thats when i saw this entry in my Nginx logs - thanks